# Firestore cloud functions http onRequest 'POST'

Tags: javascript, firebase, xmlhttprequest, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

i've set my firestore cloud function to receive an object from the request, but i get an empty body, i get he data from a Form, then pass it to a variable which i want to send in post request to my cloud firestore function, but i get an empty body, even that the cloud function runs, and i can see the log between the result.
My angular side :

```
 onSubmit(form:NgForm){
    let data = Object.assign({},form.value);
    // const httpOptions = {
    //   headers: new HttpHeaders({
    //     'Authorization': 'secret-key'
    //   }),
    //   body: 'test'
    //  };
     const dataUser = {
       displayName:data.displayName,
       email: data.email,
      password:data.password
     }


    console.log(data);
     this.http.post(this.endpoint,dataUser).subscribe(res => console.log(res));
 }
```

My node side :

```
   const functions  = require('firebase-functions');

const admin = require('firebase-admin');

admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

exports.AddUser = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) =>{

    console.log("B123oo");
     console.log(req.body);
     console.log("Boo");
    // admin.auth().createUser({
    //     email: body.email,
    //     emailVerified: false,
    //     password: body.password,
    //     displayName: body.displayName,
    //     disabled: false
    // }).then(function(userRecord){
    //     console.log("OK !!! UID: ",userRecord.uid);
    // });

 });
```

result log :

```
info: User function triggered, starting execution
B123oo
info: {}
Boo
```

Comment: Please replace the images of code with the actual code as text, and use the formatting tools of Stack Overflow to make them readable. Having the code as text makes it searchable, allows us to easily use it to test with your actual code and use it in our answer and in general is just a Good Thing to do.

Comment: You need to send back the response via `res.send(.....);` and not just use `console.log()`.  I would suggest you watch this video from Firebase: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7IkUgCLr5oA

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen done, thank you

Comment: @RenaudTarnec i don't want to send it back to view or something i want to use the data, to create an object

Comment: @Achraf I understand, however you still should send back a response in order to indicate to the Cloud Function that it is terminated. This is explained into detail in the Doug Stevenson's video I mentioned in my previous comment.

Answer (score 0):

To have a value show as req.body you don't actually assign a value to body. Body is just populated with whatever you send as your data with the request. That body would end up being your second value, dataUser. I noticed you're not passing in your httpOptions, which would normally be the 3rd argument passed to post(). That last part might be your problem. 
`this.http.post(this.endpoint,dataUser,httpOptions)`

Good resource: https://itnext.io/working-with-firebase-functions-http-request-22fd1ab644d3

Comment: I added it but still same problem

Comment: @Achraf are your httpOptions still commented out? Does dataUser have a value before it's sent to the server? Are you running firebase functions locally? or just on the server

Comment: no i took off the comment, and logged the dataUser to see if it has values in it and send it , m running it locally before deploying it, when i put the values in the functions it work fine so i think the function does not have a problem

Comment: @Achraf as far as I know Firebase functions can't reliably be run locally in this way. They can be run locally using "firebase serve" command, assuming you set up the functions in your project properly using their cli. or I usually use "firebase serve --only functions" so I can run my functions separately from my project. Once it starts running it will spit out local urls for your functions to point to. Again, assuming you set index.js up right. https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/get-started

Comment: yes i run it with the ' firebase serve ' thts where i got the url tht i pass in parameter

Comment: Hello  i've found the problem it was in the content of the header , i should've put ( 'Content-Type':  ' text/plain' )